# .NET beginner question: I connected my own database. Where can I find its TableAdapter class?

Tags: asp.net, database

I can't see it nowhere in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. The [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) that I am following is using the Northwind database and hence the need to add the code line "using NorthWindTableAdatpter;" statement.

So I thought I needed to add "using myDBTableAdapters" statement in my code which I did, but it's giving an error saying:

> "The type or namespace name 'myDbTableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

What's wrong? Where is the class for myDB's table adapter? I searched the .xsd file, but there's no mention of "myDBTableAdapters".
It's not there in the Solution Explorer.

Help?

Comment: Are you doing the tutorial step by step, or using your own names and such?  Either way, did you get to the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard as you were stepping through the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created the typed DataSet? In your solution explorer can you see a file with extension "xsd"? That's the DataSet schema file. Open that in design view and you can see your adapters there.

Comment: The design view is showing table "Products" column names and below it is writte ProductsTableAdapter
Do I need to write the statement "using ProductsTableAdapter;" or what ?  I just did this same error..sorry I am new to .net..what reference could be missing ??